# Scrolling effect with background image fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I am stuck with some paraallax effect.While visiting to some websites,I found this scrolling effect.
[here is the link](http://ibuildmart.com)

basically What actually it is.I tried fixing the background image still my background image gets move up when ever I scroll the page.Please help me.I have tried various tutorials.Still I am not able to get anything.I want scrolling effect just like the above link.There is a small strip which keeps on moving but the background image is fixed.Please help me.

[here is the link of fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v9Kvy/14/)

**css**

{

```
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    background-image:url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/View_of_Santa_Maria_del_Fiore_in_Florence.jpg');

}
#div3
{
height:400px;
    width:100%;
        background-color:lime;
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="div1">this is my first div</div>
<div id="div2">this is my second div</div>
<div id="div3">this is my third div</div>
```

Comment: Please share code through jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v9Kvy/17/ you need to add background-attachment: fixed; for #div2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your background image to be fixed, you simply need to add the correct attribute.

Add this to `#div2`

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

And this will set the image position according to the page's top left corner instead of the div's.

Answer (score 0):

Parallax effects are created by manipulating multiple image using JavaScript and CSS. To get started refer [Parallax effect tutorial](http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/recreate-nikebetterworld-parallax/) , [Some more parallax effect tutorials](http://thedesignpixel.com/best-jquery-parallax-scrolling-tutorials.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply.but did you understood what actually i want.Basically I need the same effect.Link will not work